# How to get rid of PYTHONPATH="./:${PYTHONPATH}" while running a script which uses relative imports

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, path

I have a directory as:

```
BASEDIR/
  -> codes/
      -> test.py

      -> models/
          -> __init__.py
          -> module1.py

      -> utils/
          -> __init__.py
          -> chind_module.py

      -> helpers/
          -> __init__.py
          -> submodule.py
```

I am inside the `BASEDIR` and run the code inside `test.py`  as: `python ./codes/test.py` and it gives me error as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./codes/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from models import create_model
  File "/home/shady/Desktop/Dresma/LPTN/codes/models/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from codes.utils import get_root_logger, scandir
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'codes'
```

Where **code inside `test.py` is as:**

```
from codes.models import create_model
from codes.utils.options import *

def main():
    return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Digging inside `codes/models/__init__.py`, I got that it has relative import as `from codes.helpers import *`

**But when I did `PYTHONPATH="./:${PYTHONPATH}"  python test.py`, it worked fine.**

How could I run the program without using `PYTHONPATH="./:${PYTHONPATH}"` ?

I tried the following but nothing worked

```
from models import create_model
from utils.options import *

from .models import create_model
from .utils.options import *

from ..models import create_model
from ..utils.options import *
```

Comment: make use of the first two tried lines (`from models import...`) in your **test.py** and go inside **codes** directory and run `python test.py`, and check if it works or not.

Comment: No! It does not. It throws error because `utils` uses another relative package inside.